# Java prints only last cell of data

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read content from a csv and print it out to an excel file.
So far, I have this, however it only prints out the last value of the csv into the first cell of the excel file. I tried using an increment for the column and row, but I get a null pointer exception error.

```
int i=0;
int j=0;
int k=0;
int row=68;
int column=0;
String [] part={"052","064"};
try{
    //InputStream inp = new FileInputStream();
    //Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("30_results_w_graphs.xls"));


    for (k=0; k<part.length; k++)
    {
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(part[k]);
            Cell cell = null;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(part[k]+".csv"));
        scanner.useDelimiter(",");


        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            cell=sheet.getRow(row).getCell(column);
            cell.setCellValue(scanner.next());
            //row++;
            //column++;
            }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("30_results_U_w_graphs.xls");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

I believe it is a nested for loop to increment the row and the column, but even in regular increments i get a null pointer exception.

Comment: On which line of your code, you get the NPE?

Comment: where the roww++ and column ++ have been commented off

Comment: I tried putting it like this and i got the exception on this line:
cell=sheet.getRow(row++).getCell(column++);

Comment: Make sure your `sheet` is not null, also check if `sheet.getRow(row)` does not return null and finally `row.getCell(column)` also does not return null.

Comment: I added two if statement.. if each is null, ++ them.. However it still does not write out all the data,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want to do, but this code shows some basic steps in reading a CSV file into an existing Excel file using Apache POI. Existing sheets/rows/cells will not be deleted.

The CSV file looks like this:

```
12,14,18,21
82,19,18,44
9,4,31,12
```

Read the file into a sheet named after the file name:

```
    File excel = new File("/tmp/result.xls");

    //Open existing Excel file:
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(excel);

    //Create a new Excel file:
    //Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

    //Read in CSV
    String name = "test";
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(name);
    if (sheet == null) {
        sheet = wb.createSheet(name);
    }

    int rowCount = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/tmp/" + name + ".csv"));
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] rowData = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
        for (int col = 0; col < rowData.length; col++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(rowCount);
            if (row == null)
                row = sheet.createRow(rowCount);
            Cell cell = row.getCell(col);
            if (cell == null) {
                cell = row.createCell(col);
            }
            cell.setCellValue(rowData[col]);
        }
        rowCount++;
    }

    wb.write(new FileOutputStream(excel));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, however when I open up the excel doc, it says the data is in a string format.. is there an if statement I can implement to change the data toInt() if it is an integer (some of the columns are dates) and print it as an integer?

Comment: `setCellValue()` also accepts `double`, `Date`, `Calendar` and `boolean` data types. You can convert the parsed String to the desired format, using standard Java methods. (E.g. search for "converting Java String to double")

Answer (score 0):

You don't increase `row` nor `column`. Use `createRow(int row)` and `createCell(int column)` tor creating new cells.

Comment: But it doesnt print all the data from the csv, I treads it, but prints only the last cell of data into the first cell of the excel

Comment: What is the stack trace for NPE?

Comment: How do I get the stacktrace of the NPE?

Comment: What do you have in console when NPE is thrown?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at test2.main(test2.java:113)

Comment: Press any key to continue.. that is all it says

Comment: How do you run the program? Do you use any IDE?

Comment: I use TextPadto run it

Comment: Try to run the program from cmd. We need a stack trace to say anything about the error.

Comment: I ran it through cmd and i get the same results.. nothing more